# SFDX: how to delete a package

Tags: salesforcedx, package

In the documentation, there is a command `sfdx force:package:create`. This works. If I then issue the command `sfdx force:package:list`, it perfectly shows the package I just created. Now the question is, how do i delete this package? I just created this package for testing, it doesn't have any use or meaning at all. I tried `force:package:destroy`, `force:package:delete`, `force:package:remove`, just to try if there are hidden commands out there to do this task, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the all available package command which we have right now. [package Commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm).

As of now, we don't have any command which can do this task so you need to manually delete the package from UI. Also the `sfdx force:package:create` is still in beta so SF might give this command in future but as of now, There is no option available.

Comment: hello @tushar-sharma. if UI is the only way right now, would you be kind enough to point me to the right direction on how to do that. I logged in to my trial devhub org and in the UI, i can only see scratch org infos. I cant find the created package infos.

Comment: @SamuelDev you delete a package from an org in which you have installed it.

Comment: @SamuelDev Please check the package in scratch org.

Comment: Hello @Eduard . If you are referring to the org where i installed the package (in this scenario, that would be my trailhead playground org), and then in the quick find box, typing "installed packages", and then inside the installed packages page, uninstalling the package, and further deleting the uninstalled package, yup i have already done that. However, when i run the command  `force:package:list`, the package still exists. The package is already uninstalled and deleted in the destination org. but it is not yet deleted in the DevHub.

Comment: Hello @Eric. Since I'm following trailhead, the command i used in creating the unlocked package looks like this: `sfdx force:package:create --name dreamhouse --description "My Package" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --targetdevhubusername DevHub`. My DevHub is a 30-day trial devhub org. Now inside my devhub org, if i go to the Package Manager, it doesn't have any packages. But if from the console i run the command `force:package:list`, my unlocked package is there.

Comment: @Eric Hmm, develop doesn't have packages. Build > Create > Packages and Build > Installed Packages doesn't show anything in the DevHub. And yup i'm in the right place because i only have 1 devHub.

Comment: Uninstalling a **package version** is not the same as "removing" / "deleting" the **package**. Please do not confuse. Currently, there is no way to delete a package.

Comment: Please read the OP.  The question is how to remove a package *definition* from a Dev Hub.  Not how to uninstall it from a destination org.  This would be equivalent to the old model of having a package defined in a packaging org.

Comment: @Shane yes that's why I said there is no way to do this.

Comment: I don't see packages in my hub org either.  I'm trying to configure a POST install script... Where can I navigate to the package definition via the UI?

Comment: Seems like there is also no way to do it via the UI... so this question is misleading

Answer (score 10):

It cannot currently be done by you. Perhaps Salesforce support could do it if you contacted them.

You can uninstall the package from various orgs as suggested by the previous answer. That does not eliminate the package from your package list.

```
sfdx force:package:list
```

... will still show the package even if it is uninstalled from all orgs.

I have created an idea to add this capability to the SFDX cli on the idea exchange. Go vote for it.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lMYmQAM

Comment: This is the correct answer. The answer by @Tushar Sharma misunderstood the question and confused uninstalling a **package version** with the request to delete a **package**.

Comment: Agreed 100%.  Trailhead beta isn't super useful.

Answer (score 4):

[Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_delete_unwanted_packages.htm) release enables package and version deletion:

`sfdx force:package:version:delete`

`sfdx force:package:delete`

Do take into account that deleted packages or package versions can’t be recovered, or specified as a dependency, and any new installations of the package will fail.

Released versions of second-generation managed packages can’t be deleted.

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Now, we can delete: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm

Considerations for Deleting a Package or Package Version

Deletion is permanent.
Attempts to install a deleted package version will fail.
Before deleting, ensure that the package or package version isn’t referenced as a dependency.
Examples:

```
$ sfdx force:package:delete -p "Your Package Alias"

$ sfdx force:package:delete -p 0Ho...

$ sfdx force:package:version:delete -p "Your Package Version Alias"

$ sfdx force:package:version:delete -p 04t...
```